# TDE setup with EMK in SQL SERVER 2019

Tags: sql-server, encryption, transparent-data-encryption, hsm

We are implementing  TDE in MS SQL SEREVR 2019 with EKM provider. We are using asymmetric key to encrypt the data at rest. Asymmetric key will be hosted in HSM appliances.

I have one questions regarding that.

What will be the effect if our SQL Server isn't able to connect with HSM appliances?

Will the application be able to do the normal DML process on encrypted database, as database is encrypted and it’s not able to connect with HSM appliance?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

> What will be the effect if our SQL server wont able to connect with HSM appliances ?

Well, since your key is there and is needed to encrypt and decrypt data then you're in for a whole world of pain. Typically the database will get marked as suspect.